# current_user_can( 'edit_user' ) does not work

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

I don´t clearly understand why this code does not work :

```
//Front-end profile page
global $current_user;
if ( current_user_can( 'edit_user') ) { ... }
```

$current_user output : `["allcaps"]=> array(6) { ["read"]=> bool(true) ["level_0"]=> bool(true) ["edit_user"]=> bool(true) ["view_admin_dashboard"]=> bool(true) ["subscriber"]=> bool(true) ["client"]=> bool(true) }`

So, that is in the list !

even if I do this :

```
$role = get_role('client');
$role->add_cap('edit_user');
global $current_user;
if ( current_user_can( 'edit_user') ) { ... }
```

that does not work as well.

But with the capability 'read', that works perfectly.

Someone can help me and explain what happens ?

Comment: It does work for me (when I'm logged in as an Administrator). Are you sure you are looking at the right user with those correct capabilities? Have you put in a relevant 'if' and 'else' statement to check what's returned?

Comment: `edit_user` is not a capability that should be assigned to a role or user. The correct capability is `edit_users`. `edit_user` is a _meta capability_ that is mapped to a real capability based on other logic, and needs to be passed a specific user ID.